# How to publish npm package to private nexus repository

Tags: node.js, npm

I have created a sample react app which I have published to npm repository so I can install them into some other react project. Now I want to publish the same package to Nexus repository so it would be private and I am not able to figure out how to do this. I have tried the following command

```
npm config set registry "https://my-custom-registry.registry.nodesource.io/"
```

but when I am trying to publish my npm repo there It giving me an authentication error. what are the other steps I need to perform?

Answer (score 0):

if Nexus 3 use token bearer token, if use nexus 2 you have to use basic authentication

```
registry=http://.......
always-auth=true
email=mail@mail.test
_auth=ZGV2ZWxvcGVyOmRldmVsb3BlcjEyMw==
```

this is file .npmrc

i had same error and with this i works like a charm